# Passing PHP variable in hidden form input

Tags: php, html, forms

kinda simple I know but it's frustrating the hell out of me.

I have this page with the following form.

```
<?php
$loc = ip_info("Visitor", "Country");
?>

<form id="contact" method="post" class="login">
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="note">
<input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo $loc ?>">
<input type="text" name="title" onKeydown='Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) SubmitFormData();' placeholder="Who are you?" id="title">
<input type="text" placeholder="What do you want?" name="message" id="message" onKeydown='Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) SubmitFormData();' >
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="" />
</form>
```

This code basically takes the form data and passes it along to a php file called post.php which contains the following.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['title'])) $tit=$_POST['title'];
echo $tit;
echo $_POST['title'];
echo $_POST['message'];
echo $_POST['type'];
echo $_POST['location'];
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['title'] = $_POST['title'];
$post_data['body'] = $_POST['message'];
$post_data['type'] = $_POST['type'];
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes');
//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer']);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
var_dump($result); 
header("Location: http://www.example.com/pb/");
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is have the form post 4 variables from the HTML form, the title, message, type and location.

They are all posting fine, except for the location field. When I set it as type="text" in the HTML side, it pulls the location correctly and displays a field with the right location in it. But when it tries to post the data to the PHP side it fails, giving only one visible error in the error_log which is underfined index for the location variable on line 11.

After I get the location to POST correctly from the HTML side, I want to add it to the title variable that's being passed along to the curl query, that way, the message that is sent using pushbullets API contains the title as "Location: Name" location being the location pulled from the PHP method on the first page, and name being the title field passed along from the form.

Wow, I'm starting to confuse myself. Anyway, please let me know if you can help.

Comment: not sure if that's it, but in the php echo, you don't have a semicolon after the variable: `<?php echo $loc; ?>` instead of `<?php echo $loc ?>`

Comment: @Johannes - If you only have one statement inside the `<?php ... ?>` you don't need a semicolon.

Comment: If you check the rendered HTML for the form, does it look correct? And I didn't really understand, is it only that hidden field that doesn't get posted (when it's hidden), but it works when it's not?

Comment: HTML render looks perfect. And this field is not getting posted, hidden or not.

Comment: What does `SubmitFormData()` do?

Comment: It submits the form data to post.php

Comment: Could you show us that code as well? That's the only link in the chain that we haven't seen. The rest looks like it should work.

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver. I didn't even notice this script was there in the first place. I'm editing it now to add the location variable.

Comment: function SubmitFormData() {     var title = $("#title").val();     var message = $("#message").val();     var type = $("#type").val();   var location = $("#location").val();  $.post("post.php", { title: title, message: message, type: type, location: location} ); document.getElementById("contact").reset(); }

Comment: Just post the complete form like this: `$.post('post.php', $("#contact").serialize());` and all form elements will be posted, even if you add more to your form later on.

Comment: It's working perfectly now! You are amazing my friend. Thank you very much! :)